# Is it ok to use the same UpgradeCode for an .msi and the WiX bundle that wraps it

Tags: wix

I have inherited a code base containing a WiX based installer. That installer is made up of a separate WiX project that generates an .msi file and another WiX project that generates a bootstrapper .exe.

The boostrapper .exe simply wraps the .msi file and installs it. But what irritates me is that both the .msi and .exe WiX projects use the same value for the `UpgradeCode`. More specifically, in the .wxs file of the .msi project the attribute `Product/@UpgradeCode` is the same value as the attribute `Bundle/@UpgradeCode` in the .wxs file of the .exe project.

Would using the same value cause any upgrade issues in that particular case?

The product hasn't shipped yet and there is still time to change it. But do I need to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no practical issue using the same UpgradeCode. MSI packages and Burn track them independently.

The one reason I consider changing one (if not shipped ever) is to make searching log files easier. With unique values you don't have to look at additional context to know which UpgradeCode your dealing with.

We look at a lot of log files at FireGiant so little things like that make life a little clearer.